# Detect the Moon in image

Tags: python, opencv

I was trying to detect the moon in images. I have tried with template but it doesn't work properly. I have used a lot of templates, but no good result. Also I need to pay attention to the execution time(It need to be as less as possible)...
Can you help me with this.

I have tried this code, with this template, and a lot of test-images.
[template image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xuAnc.jpg)
[test image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gY4wD.jpg)

```
img = cv2.imread('test_img.jpg')
img_gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
template = cv2.imread('template.jpg', 0)
template = cv2.blur(template, (5,5))
w,h = template.shape[::-1]
res = cv2.matchTemplate(img_gray, template, cv2.TM_SQDIFF)
min_val, max_val, min_loc, max_loc = cv2.minMaxLoc(res)
top_left = min_loc
bottom_right = (top_left[0] + w, top_left[1] + h)
cv2.rectangle(img, top_left, bottom_right, (255,0,0), 2)
```

This code can find moon even in not-related images, but did not find in moon-image:
[Wrong result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rCunR.jpg)
[detects Nothing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tdOKa.png)

Comment: If you have only this kind of images of the moon a simple threshold will work, no ?

Comment: @Lelouch images can be could be anything,even no_moon images, and I need to  classify images: "with moon" and "others". You mean to threshold the images?

Comment: Train a DNN classifier like EfficientNet B0 with enough data.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the matchTemplate method of cv2.TM_SQDIFF which isn't ideal in this situation as that algorithm isn't very good at identifying images with low contrast. Try cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED

I just tested it with your code and it drew a red square over the moon. Also, if your image is already in grayscale it may throw an error. Try adding a check for if the image is already greyscale for the line:

```
img_gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
```

Do you have the full source code so I can try and further assist? Its possible the error is with another piece of code but there isn't a whole lot to go off of.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way to detect the moon in Python/OpenCV.

- Read the input
- Convert to grayscale
- Otsu Threshold
- Use HoughCircles to find the circle
- Draw the circle on a copy of the input
- Save the result

Input:

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# read the image
img = cv2.imread('moon.jpg')
h, w = img.shape[:2]

# convert to grayscale
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# threshold
tval, thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
#print(tval)

# find the circle
circle_img = img.copy()
max_size = min(h,w)//2
min_size = min(h,w)//8
circles = cv2.HoughCircles(gray, cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1, minDist=min_size, param1=150, param2=50, minRadius=min_size, maxRadius=max_size)
for circle in circles[0]:
    (x,y,r) = circle
    x = int(x)
    y = int(y)
    r = int(r)
    print("x:", x, "y:", y, "r:", r)
    cv2.circle(circle_img, (x, y), r, (0, 0, 255), 1)

# save results
cv2.imwrite('moon_circle.jpg', circle_img)

# show results
#cv2.imshow('thresh1', thresh1)
cv2.imshow('thresh', thresh)
cv2.imshow('circle', circle_img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Circle:

[image]

Comment: This is a very elegant solution. Well done sir. Have an upvote

Comment: The problem is ,what if the image contains also planet, I need to detect only moon, not the other 'circles' . That's why I try with template.

Comment: Please be more specific about your requirements in the future and show examples that are appropriate.